# Strange characters when consuming JSON web service

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm consuming a JSON WebService by using the WebClient.DOwnloadStringAsync. The returning string contains some strange character pair:

```
"start_address" : "GoethestraÃŸe 7-9, Monaco di Baviera, Germania",
```

In place of some extended charachter. How can I see the correct one? In the example it sould be: **ß**

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the correct Character(s) are you doing any kind of odd URL.Encoding..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved Myself:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // Specify the encoding here
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the encoding of the German "Double S" character, still used in the word Strasse in parts of Germany. Switching to UTF8 should solve your problem.

Comment: As I understand it, "Strasse" is used only in Switzerland; "Straße" is the standard spelling in Germany and Austria.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I learn't German before the spelling reform of 1996 so I sometimes get these things a little muddled.